# Meaning of "as of" in this context

Tags: sentence-meaning

A fragment from a news article:

> While sharing jokes and memes on social media sites by these renowned personalities is completely fine, there is always a limit to **as of** what is considered to be funny and not in a bad taste.

From the perspective of time "**as of**" means: from, up to and on.

Please explain "**as of**" in this context.

Thank you.

Comment: Explanation: clumsy, ungrammatical writing by a lazy journalist, possibly not a native speaker, or alternatively hasty or careless editing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey sir, could you tell me what should have been written?

Comment: Looks like they were trying to write "a limit as to what is considered..." and ended up making a mistake. There's also a mistake later on, when they say "in a bad taste" instead of just "in bad taste."

Comment: Suggests either non-native or clumsy writer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on the false premise that *as of* has been used grammatically or idiomatically.